# How to show frequency values in y-axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to show histogram of frequency distribution

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [10,20,20,30,30,30,40,40,50,50]

mu, std = norm.fit(data)

plt.hist(data, bins='auto', density=True, alpha=1, color='navy')
plt.grid()

xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 10)
p = norm.pdf(x, mu, std)
plt.plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

I get unknown numbers in the y-axis.

I want to get the frequency of the values.
For example: the frequency of 10 is 1,  the frequency of 20 is 2.[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYuux.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are plotting a PDF, hence the frequency is not shown but the probability for each data value.

I think you might be looking for something like this!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [10,20,20,30,30,30,40,40,50,50]
plt.hist(data, bins='auto', alpha=1)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(np.unique(data, return_counts=True)[0],np.unique(data, return_counts=True)[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the frequency:

```
np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
```

if you want to do an histogram, with frequency of the y-axis just use `density=False` (which is the default)

But probably since you want to compare with a gaussian distribution, you want to use `density=True`.